# сериализация xml

Tags: c#, .net

При сериализации объекта символы `<` и `>` выводятся не так **(последняя строка файла)**

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfUser_Ser xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <User_Ser>
    <Login>Tat@nk@</Login>
    <Password>Tanya123</Password>
    <Name>Татьяна</Name>
    <Sername>Шебаниц</Sername>
    <Address>
      <Country>Украина</Country>
      <Region>Донецкая</Region>
      <City>Мариуполь</City>
      <Street>Пашковского</Street>
      <House_number>41</House_number>
      <Room>8</Room>
    </Address>
    <Phone>0962234923</Phone>
  </User_Ser>
  <User_Ser>
    <Login>MACTEPwar</Login>
    <Password>Accessdeniedroma2005</Password>
    <Name>Виталий</Name>
    <Sername>Шебаниц</Sername>
    <Address>
      <Country>Украина</Country>
      <Region>Донецкая</Region>
      <City>Мариуполь</City>
      <Street>Пашковского</Street>
      <House_number>41</House_number>
      <Room>8</Room>
    </Address>
    <Phone>0678838348</Phone>
  </User_Ser>&lt;User_Ser&gt;&lt;Login&gt;SePoGa&lt;/Login&gt;&lt;Password&gt;Ser123&lt;/Password&gt;&lt;Name&gt;Сергей&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;Sername&gt;Шебаниц&lt;/Sername&gt;&lt;Address&gt;&lt;Country&gt;Украина&lt;/Country&gt;&lt;Region&gt;Донецкая&lt;/Region&gt;&lt;City&gt;Мариуполь&lt;/City&gt;&lt;Street&gt;Пашковского&lt;/Street&gt;&lt;House_number&gt;41&lt;/House_number&gt;&lt;Room&gt;8&lt;/Room&gt;&lt;/Address&gt;&lt;Phone&gt;0962234924&lt;/Phone&gt;&lt;/User_Ser&gt;&lt;User_Ser&gt;&lt;Login&gt;SePoGa&lt;/Login&gt;&lt;Password&gt;Ser123&lt;/Password&gt;&lt;Name&gt;Сергей&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;Sername&gt;Шебаниц&lt;/Sername&gt;&lt;Address&gt;&lt;Country&gt;Украина&lt;/Country&gt;&lt;Region&gt;Донецкая&lt;/Region&gt;&lt;City&gt;Мариуполь&lt;/City&gt;&lt;Street&gt;Пашковского&lt;/Street&gt;&lt;House_number&gt;41&lt;/House_number&gt;&lt;Room&gt;8&lt;/Room&gt;&lt;/Address&gt;&lt;Phone&gt;0962234924&lt;/Phone&gt;&lt;/User_Ser&gt;</ArrayOfUser_Ser>
```

Сериализация:

```
public static void setUsers(List<User_Ser> users)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(pathToFile);
            foreach (User_Ser user in users)
            {
                XmlNode xnode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "User_Ser", null);
                XmlSerializer xSeriz = new XmlSerializer(typeof(User_Ser));
                XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                ns.Add("", "");
                XmlWriterSettings writtersetting = new XmlWriterSettings();
                writtersetting.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                using (XmlWriter xmlwriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(sw, writtersetting))
                {
                    xSeriz.Serialize(xmlwriter, user, ns);
                }

                byte[] symbol = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(sw.ToString()); //Получаем байт символа "Я" в кодировке 1251

                Console.WriteLine(symbol[0]); // посмотрев таблицу символов кодировки 1251 в википедии было установлено что символу я соответствует значение "DF" в 16 в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления =  223 в десятичной

                string binary = Convert.ToString(symbol[0], 2); //перевели байт в двоичную систему и получили "11011111" = 223 = DF
                // Console.WriteLine(binary);

                symbol[0] = Convert.ToByte(binary, 2); //перевели обратно в десятичную и получили опять 223 = DF 

                string r = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(symbol); //Преобразовали обратно в строку

                xnode.InnerText = r;
                XmlNode bindxnode = xnode.SelectSingleNode("User_Ser");
                foreach (XmlNode ch in xnode)
                {
                    doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(ch);
                }

            }
            doc.Save(pathToFile);
        }
```

> Как вывести их в нормальном виде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"не так" - не как?

Это нормальное кодирование для служебных xml-символов, встречающихся в `innerText` и значениях атрибутов xml-элементов.

```
xnode.InnerText = r;
```

Подозреваю, что Вы хотели назначить `InnerXml` - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.innerxml?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Пожалуйста. Рад был помочь.